# Uncovered lines not shown in sfdx deploy (check only) command anymore

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, code-coverage

Our CI/CD pipeline has not been changed in past 4 months, But i clearly remember in case of code coverage issue. Uncovered lines used to popup.

Was there any change in sfdx command where we need to specify a param to get the uncovered lines? Because it becomes extremely difficult to debug this, as our lower orgs are not in sync always?

Now it shows result like this:

```
=== Component Failures [0]
Type  Name  Problem
────  ────  ───────


=== Test Results Summary
Passing: 16
Failing: 0
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed.
Total: 16
Time: 0
```

I clearly remember earlier we used to get all uncovered lines also along with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there was a change, you now need to include the `--verbose` flag to get the coverage.

This happened several releases ago (not entirely sure when)

Comment: Thanks a lot, was scratching my head around this for few days.